# second order accuracy in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-derivative, rounding-error

When I read finite difference method I encountered the below formula which is used to approximate the second order PDE:
$$ \frac{d^{2}u(x)}{dx^{2}} = \frac{u(x+h)-2u(x)+u(x-h)}{h^2}- \frac{h^2}{12}\frac{d^4u(\xi)}{dx^4} \quad \quad \text{where} \xi_- \leq \xi \leq \xi_+ $$
The formula gives an approximation of $\frac{d^{2}u(x)}{dx^{2}}$ with a second order accuracy $O(h^2)$.
What does this second order accuracy mean in practice (assuming I know value of h)?

Comment: It tells you how the error scales with $h$. The second order accuracy $O(h^2)$ means each time you halve the grid spacing, the error is divided by a factor of $2^2=4$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a question. Can we assume the residual error of estimation <1/4?

Comment: It depends how small $u''''(\xi)$ and $h$ are. Not in general.

Comment: I want to use it for discretization of pde. I have no idea how can I calculate $u^{''''}$. I was thinking whether or not I can just use $h^2$ as an upper bound for error.